# Reconciling Php Version on OSX Mavericks

Tags: php, macos

I have recently upgraded my OSX to Mavericks. Before the upgrade I had two copies PHP version 5.3. One was running for Apache and one for Command line.  This was fine, until after the upgrade I now have PHP 5.4 running on Apache BUT still have 5.3 running for command line. I need to bring these to the same version.  Worst case, I would get a new copy of 5.4 running for command line, and best case I would just configure the command line to use the pre installed copy of php. I have tried to add the folder location for my apache copy of php to my path,  but it didn't work. 
Any help on this would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it. I couldn't find this answer anywhere so hopefully this will be helpful to someone.
I created test.php with

```
echo exec("which php");
```

And ran that. Then I ran

```
which php
```

from the command line. Then I made the symlink which from command line point at the location found by looking at test.php with my browser.